# Secondary click does not register even though it is checked on (MacOS Big Sur)

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, imac-pro

So I just updated to macOS Big Sur from Mojave. I had zero problems with right-clicking before the update, nor did I face them immediately after updating. However, after I shut down my iMac Pro, and started it after a while, I cannot right-click. So far, I have tried:

- Restarting(several times)
- Shutting down my mouse and powering it up again
- Deleting the mouse from  Bluetooth section of System preferences and reconnecting it with a USB.

So far, nothing has worked. I will appreciate all help!

Best regards

Edit: Re-installing the macOS Big Sur fixed the problem, but I would like to know if a more convenient method exists, should the problem repeat itself in future.

Comment: Have you looked in the SystemPreferences -> Mouse and confirmed that the secondary click is still set as before? I've read others saying it became unchecked after the upgrade.

Comment: @MrR Sorry for the late reply, but I have. I have tried setting it to left-click, and even then the secondary click was not registering. I turned it back to right-click, and the same problem. I reinstalled Big Sur just now, and the problem seems solved maybe? But I'd like to know about a less tedious approach if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-installed Big Sur on my machine, by booting into the recovery mode. That seems to have solved the problem. However, if there are more convenient solutions than this, please let me know and I will select that as the accepted answer. Thanks!